# How to show html preview from html String in CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

JavaScript

```
var preview = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'mailViewer' );
     preview.setHtml($('#mail-content').html());
```

Html

```
<span id="mail-content" th:text="${mailReceived.body}" style="display:none;"></span>
<div id="mailViewer"></div>
```

output
  [image]

i'm trying to set HTML String in CKEDITOR but it is not showing HTML preview. How to make it show html preview

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct you should do like this

```
CKEDITOR.instances['mailViewer'].setData($('#mail-content').html())
```

Comment: i'm getting same output